# Why is the runtime for this O(n)?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

so in class we went over this bit of Java, and we were told to find the runtime.

```java
for(int i=0; i<N; i=i+2){
            for(int j=N; j<N; j++){
                for(int k=0; k<N; k++){
                    System.out.println(i*j);
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<100; k++){
            System.out.println(k);
        }
```

Apparently the runtime for this is O(*n*) but I don't know why. Wouldn't this be O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) because of the for loops? Are there any tips or tricks to being able to tell immediately what the runtime is that I am missing?

Comment: How many iterations does the loop on `j` execute? (Once you put in the missing semicolons.)

Comment: oh i see. 0 times. So the first loops runs o(n) times and the k loop runs 100 times therefore its o(n)?

Comment: `for(int j=N; j<N; j++){` essentially means "do not run this"

Answer (score 0):

For the given code, you should have the following time complexity:

```
T(n) = 1 + N/2 (1 + 2) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 100 (1 + 2) ≈ N/2
```

This means that your overall complexity is `O(n)`. Because the second `for` loop (the first nested `for` loop) never executes, due to its condition, you don't have `O(n^3)` complexity. If the second `for` loop was written as `for(int j=0; j< N; j++)`, then you would have `O(n^3)` complexity.